# Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10 on Like where clause

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

Might get some negative points here but feel the need to post an problem (And self-defined solution) that I could not match to anything on the interweb...

I have a very simple bit of code that returns the queries that my company's SSRS RDL datasets uses to obtain data.

It works nicely when returning all data, but the moment I add a where clause to only return records with specific text within the data set *like* the parameter I get an error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10 ...
>   String or binary data would be truncated

The parameter is defined exactly the same as the column I am searching in is (`NVARCHAR(MAX)`).

I know what that error means ("The error means that you're trying to put a value into a table that is larger than what the column can hold. I.e. you're to insert a `varchar(100)` into a column that's been defined as `varchar(80)`.") but what stumped me was that the flippen thing only errors out when run the query with the where clause.

I managed to narrow the culprit record down to one having 12351 characters (Using LEN).

The solution that I found was to change the LIKE to an =.  Not 100% ideal because I would like the flexibility to search for any text within the column, but I can live with it.

Comment: Yes, you deserve down votes. You did not give an example of your original query nor an example of your "fixed" query nor any sample data that caused the first query to fail. That makes your solution impossible to understand for anyone else. Perhaps the key here is using tsql to access RDL files - but who knows what you were trying to do.

Comment: My apologies for not adding code detail.  My intention was to give people who might have a similar issue some guidance.

Can not add the code because it references the RDL's xml and trying to put that into an example without exposing my data is a bit beyond my level of expertise.

Comment: @WiaanvanAswegen If you plan on self answering a question (which is encouraged) then you should post the answer in the answer box rather than in the question body :)

Comment: Oooh.  Makes sense it does thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `LIKE` operator in following manner:

```
WHERE myColumn LIKE '%some text%`
```

which I suspect you do from your description:

> to search for any text within the column

Then, you can replace it with `WHERE CHARINDEX('some text', myColumn) > 0` and see if it will work.

Comment: Thank you Michael.  I tried that and it passed the error but did not return the intended result.  (Kudos for the correct assumptions).